# why parameter value null when second controller loads in mvc, c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Note : I'm new to MVC

In my case it has two views and two controllers.I am passing selected item value to the the second controller from first view using ajax.passing is success.
but when second view appears , the value is null.Is this ajax problem or mvc. I can't understand.

***this is my first controller and first view***

```
 public ActionResult First()
        {
            //get the location data
            var Loc = getData("Location", "", "", "");
            List<Firstdata> llc = new List<Firstdata>();
            foreach (var val in Loc)
            {
                llc.Add(new Firstdata
                {
                    Destination =val
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Loc = llc;
            return View();
        }
```

***first view***

```
   <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label>Destination</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="destination">

                        @foreach (var item1 in @ViewBag.Loc)
                        {
                            <option>@item1.Destination</option>

                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="btn" id="bud">
                        @Html.ActionLink("GO", "Check","Cruise")
                    </div>

                </div>
```

***ajax passing in first view***

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#bud a").click(function () {
        var destination = $("#destination").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Check","Cruise")',
            data: { 'destination': destination },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "XML",
            //contentType: "application/xml",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                if (!data)
                    alert("no xml data returned");
                else {
                    alert("success");

                }
                //location.href = "~/Views/Cruise/Check.cshtm";
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

***this is my second controller***

```
  public ActionResult Check(string destination)
        {

            XElement rootele = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/CruiseData/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
            var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(l => l.Element("Location").Value == destination)
                                .Select(s => s.Element("Name").Value);

            List<Details> d = new List<Details>();
           foreach(var itm in getneededData)
           {
               d.Add(new Details
               {
                   cruiseName = itm
               });
           }

           ViewBag.needed = d;

            return View();



          }
```

** In this point destination is not null and d(ViewBag.needed) is also not null.it shows the count

***this is my second view***

```
<div>

      @foreach (var itme in @ViewBag.needed)
      {
          <h2>@itme</h2>
      }
    </div>
```

in here loop go through for @ViewBag.needed count and finally display null.no idea what is going.
please help me with this.

Comment: `if(d.Count > 0)` then do the loop. it will give an idea whether `d` has any data or not. did you debugged it ? you can also cast back to see the data like i.e `(List<Details>)@ViewBag.needed`. also check if your `string destination` has a value or not ?

Comment: I seem to be confused about the use of ajax here. Seems like you are giving an action link and still using ajax for generating a click event. Try the action click without ajax.

Comment: it can't use to send the select item

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a routing problem there. If you are using default routing that is

```
    routes.MapRoute(name:"Default",
url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults:new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

then you need to chagne controller parameter name destination to id
 as:

```
public ActionResult Check(string id)
        {
```

and in JQuery call change it as

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Check","Cruise")',
            data: { 'id': destination },
```

Or
you can add new route in RouteConfig.cs as

```
routes.MapRoute(name:"Default",
url:"{controller}/{action}/{destination}",
defaults:new { controller = "Cruise", action = "Check" }
);
```

For routing you can refer to http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/MVC/routing-in-mvc-4/20190